# highcharter error: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, highcharts

I have 2 examples of using highcharter package down below; first one is from textbook which can be executed normally and the 2nd one is one that I modify a bit and an error comes out, would be awesome if u can take a look. Can't thank u enough.

```
library(quantmod)
library(purrr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

symbols<-c("SPY","EFA","IJS","EEM","AGG")

prices<-
  getSymbols(symbols,
             src='yahoo',
             from="2012-12-31",
             to="2017-12-31",
             auto.assign=TRUE,
             warning=FALSE) %>%
  map(~Ad(get(.))) %>%
  reduce(merge)%>%
  `colnames<-`(symbols)

prices_monthly<-to.monthly(prices, 
                           indexAt = "lastof",
                           OHLC=FALSE)

asset_return_xts<-
  Return.calculate(prices_monthly,
                   method="log")%>%
  na.omit()

highchart(type="stock")%>%
  hc_title(text="monthly log ret")%>%
  hc_add_series(asset_return_xts[,symbols[1]],
                 name=symbols[1])%>%
  hc_add_series(asset_return_xts[,symbols[2]],
                name=symbols[2])%>%
  hc_add_series(asset_return_xts[,symbols[3]],
                name=symbols[3])%>%
  hc_add_series(asset_return_xts[,symbols[4]],
                name=symbols[4])%>%
  hc_add_series(asset_return_xts[,symbols[5]],
                name=symbols[5])%>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat())%>%
  hc_navigator(enabled=FALSE)%>%
  hc_scrollbar(enabled=FALSE)%>%
  hc_exporting(enabled=TRUE)%>%
  hc_legend(enabled=TRUE)
```

The first example from above works very well, however, an error comes out after I shorten the list of 5 to a list of 4.

```
airline_stock<-c("AAL","LUV","DAL","UAL")

airline_prices<-
  getSymbols(airline_stock,
             src='yahoo',
             from="2015-12-31",
             to="2018-12-31",
             auto.assign=TRUE,
             warning=FALSE) %>%
  map(~Ad(get(.))) %>%
  reduce(merge)%>%
  `colnames<-`(airline_stock)

airline_prices_monthly<-to.monthly(airline_prices, 
                                   indexAt = "lastof",
                                   OHLC=FALSE) 

airline_asset_return_xts<-
  Return.calculate(airline_prices_monthly,
                   method="log")%>%
  na.omit()


highchart(type="stock")%>%
  hc_title(text="monthly log ret")%>%
  hc_add_series(airline_asset_return_xts[,symbols[1]],
                name=symbols[1])%>%
  hc_add_series(airline_asset_return_xts[,symbols[2]],
                name=symbols[2])%>%
  hc_add_series(airline_asset_return_xts[,symbols[3]],
                name=symbols[3])%>%
  hc_add_series(airline_asset_return_xts[,symbols[4]],
                name=symbols[4])%>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat())%>%
  hc_navigator(enabled=FALSE)%>%
  hc_scrollbar(enabled=FALSE)%>%
  hc_exporting(enabled=TRUE)%>%
  hc_legend(enabled=TRUE)



Error in `[.xts`(airline_asset_return_xts, , symbols[4]) :

  subscript out of bounds
```

As mentioned, the only change here is instead of a list of 5, I use a list of 4 and an error comes out saying subscript out of bounds.

Comment: In the second example, you refer to `symbols` in your `hc_add_series` - a vector of 5 different symbols found in the first example (compare with `airline_stock` a vector of 4 different symbols in second example)...this probably works if you replace `symbols` with `airline_stock` in your second example, such as `hc_add_series(airline_asset_return_xts[,airline_stock[1]], name=airline_stock[1])`...

Comment: @Ben, thanks man, it works perfectly now !!